# How to run GNU utilities without root?

Tags: command-line

Is there any way to use GNU utilities like GNU's sed, find, bash, and awk WITHOUT root? Android's utilities that are provided by toolbox and the BusyBox applets provided by one particular application I have installed lack the kind of features necessary for them to be fully functional.

One problem I have in particular is that I have no way of converting characters that hinder processing data in a Unix environment (such as linefeeds and nulls) into their respective escape codes (i.e., a linefeed becomes `\n`, a null becomes `\x00` or `\0`, etc.).

I am running Android 4.4.

Comment: Get or compile static binaries of utilities you need. Set a custom PATH to these binaries in any Terminal app and use

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux)! (Note: I'm not affliated with it or its author)

Termux provides a full set of common Linux CLI tools like GNU coreutils, binutils, and popular software like imagemagick, ffmpeg, as well as development environment like Clang, Python and Ruby. Other nice gadgets also include Vim, Emacs, tmux, htop, etc.

All available without root.

[image]
<sup>Image from Google Play details page</sup>

Comment: I cannot install it. The Play Store says it is not compatible with the available version. I did say I am running Android 4.4.

Comment: @Melab Then I don't know any other alternatives. Maybe get another device that runs 5.0+?